How to change response code in gwt-rpc calls?
I want to know how to change the response code of gwt-rpc calls. During success or even failure (when Exception is thrown), the response code is always 200 from server-side. See below code for example.
This is my client-side code
private void doSomething(String something) {
      service.doSomething(something, new AsyncCallback<Boolean>() {
          @Override
          public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                
          }

          @Override
          public void onSuccess(Boolean result) {
                
          }
       }
   });
}

And my server-side code looks like this
public class ServiceImpl extends AbstractXsrfProtectedServiceServlet implements Service {

 public boolean doSomething(String something) throws Exception {
       if(!something.isEmpty()) {
          try {
              log("Something done");
              return true
          } catch (UnAuthorizedException uae) {
            //....Do Something so that the response from server is 401 instead of 200.
          }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

In this case, The response from server-side to client-side always has the status code 200. i.e, during

the method returns true.
the method returns false.
An Exception is thrown from method
In all the scenarios, the response code is 200.

An example response from server to client looks like this in case Exception is thrown,
HTTP/1.1 200 200
Server: Apache
Content-Disposition: attachment
Content-Length: 288
X-XSS-Protection: 0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8

> //EX[0,5,67,4,3,["UnAuthorizedException/2807456106","UnAuthorizedException$ErrorCode/634580222","You are unauthorized to perform this action"],2,8]


So I want to know if there's a way to catch relevant exceptions as I've commented, and set the current rpc call's response to something that we want, like 400, 401, etc instead of 200.

While you can do this, if the status code isn't 200, the client AsyncCallback will receive an onFailure call with a StatusCodeException. This is because a non-200 code means "something was wrong with the network call to the server" instead of "something went wrong with your method call on the server". You must be sure that you want to handle failure in this way.
Instead, GWT-RPC encodes the failure in the 200 OK response as an exception. Successful responses start with //OK[..., while failures begin with //EX[.... Then, the serialized object in the payload will represent an exception object that the RemoteService subtype's method declared.
If the failure is something that should be part of how the client application communicates with the server application, it should probably be declared as part of the RemoteService type.
If you have a proxy or a filter trying to intervene and say "wait this call can't happen because XYZ", then it might make sense to send a different status code - and the client application must handle that by testing for StatusCodeExceptions.

I am sorry, I am not understanding it fully. "If the status code isn't 200, the client AsyncCallback will receive an onFailure call with a StatusCodeException". Here, the case you are referring to, is when the server call failed due to some reason so it returns some non-200 code. What about the scenarios when the server call is fine as I mentioned in my question and I want to manually set the status code to something else? Or does it mean that if I throw a StatusCodeException from server, it will change the status code in the response?

If you change the status code to not-200, the client will not handle the response correctly - your payload will be replaced with a client-side StatusCodeException, unless you also rewrite how the client RPC implementation works. Can you describe why you want this, what you hope to achieve - there might be another way to resolve it?

Actually, that is all I wanted to do. I wanted to know if it was possible to change the status code in gwt-rpc response.

Hey, Can you please provide the gwt documentation related to this, somewhere where it mentions about status codes or how it handles the client server calls?

This would be a better conversation to have in chat than in comments, join us at https://matrix.to/#/#gwtproject_gwt:gitter.im. That said, the javadoc on StatusCodeException is quite clear https://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/StatusCodeException.html "...if the HTTP response from the server does not have a 200 status code." The caller is clear too, if you need something clearer than docs: https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/89d06d61e2e7ee3007d4cbeabe60e0f28da18467/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/impl/RequestCallbackAdapter.java#L208-L209

Just answering part of your question here. If you want to manipulate the response in GWT-RPC servlet, you could firstly get the response object via the following:
HttpServletResponse resp = getThreadLocalResponse();

Then, you can do whatever you need with the resp object, for example, change the status code.

I tried that and set the status code to something else. I was still getting 200 in response. Not sure if I did something wrong.

If you could arrange some minimum runnable demo code, it will be easy to identify the problem.

Not sure if that's possible. I will try
